# N/A An object 'casePortfolioManagement' of type LightningComponentBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: visualstudiocode

When I deploy 'casePortfolioManagement' LWC code to Sandbox using Visual Studio Tool then I started getting below error:
**N/A An object 'casePortfolioManagement' of type LightningComponentBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory**

I have tried to retrieve complete code from Sandbox and just made simple change on .js file and could not deploy it.
FYI: My package.xml has below for LightningComponentBundle :

```
<types>
 <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexComponent</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexPage</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexTrigger</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>StaticResource</name>
</types>
<version>49.0</version>
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue as I this was working perfectly till yesterday. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tool are you using to retrieve and deploy? What API version? Can you share the package XML?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I am using Visual Studio Tool.The API version in package.xml is 49. Below is the Package.xml:
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name> 
    </types>

<< Trimming the XML to fit in the response >>
Thanks.

Comment: You can edit the question to add package xml? Also which command is getting executed in vscode terminal?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, Thanks I updated the same.

Comment: What commands or functions are you using for deploying? is it source:deploy or mdapi:deploy?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, 
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I just checked XML is missing in the component every time I am retrieving, not sure. When I created "casePortfolioManagement.js-meta" manually in the tool and deployed then it successfully deployed. Thanks for your suggestions that helped me to look closer.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked XML is missing in the component every time I am retrieving, not sure. When I created "casePortfolioManagement.js-meta" manually in the tool and deployed then it successfully deployed.

Comment: You should raise a support ticket with salesforce to figure why this happened? This sounds like a bug to me

Comment: Sure Thanks. @MohithShrivastava